# Use of "will be taking" instead of "will take"

Tags: future-continuous

> The moment you put your soda can down you **will be taking** better care

I read this sentence in a newspaper article and I would like to know why she used "will be taking" instead of "will take"

Comment: I just did a Google search for this sentence, and the only hit that came back was to this question. Moreover, it doesn't look like a complete sentence. Please tell us more about the original context. Share a link if you can. Confirm the sentence was transcribed correctly. And please don't type your sentence as your title and then only say "I read this sentence in the newspaper." The sentence we are being asked to analyze should be in the question itself. I've made a few edits to improve this, but please read the _Details, Please_ meta post and add a few more details. Then we can reopen this.

Comment: I think it's a good question (at least as it shows now).